# Surjective homomorphisms of non-connected Lie groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups

Let $\psi\colon B\to C$
be a  homomorphism of real Lie groups, where the group $C$ is connected.
Let $B^0$ denote the identity component of $B$, and we set $\pi_0(B)=B/B^0$, then $\pi_0(B)$ is a discrete group.

> **Question 1.** Assume that the homomorphism $\psi$ is surjective.
>   What conditions on $\pi_0(B)$ will imply that $\psi(B^0)=C$ ?

**Counter-example.**  If $C$ is any nontrivial connected Lie group,
and we take for $B$ the abstract group $C$ with discrete topology,
then the natural homomorphism $\psi\colon B\to C$ is surjective, but $B^0=\{1_B\}$, hence $\psi(B^0)=\{1_C\}\ne C$.

> **Lemma.**
>   Let $B$ be a Lie group such that $\pi_0(B)$ is *finite*,
>   and let $\psi\colon B\to C$ be a surjective homomorphism of Lie groups.
>   Then $\psi(B^0)=C^0$.

*Proof.*
Let $\mu$ be a left-invariant measure on $C$.
If $\psi(B^0)\ne C$, then $\mu(\psi(B^0))=0$,
hence $0\le\mu(\psi(B))\le\#\pi_0(B)\cdot\mu(\psi(B^0))=0$,
and we obtain that $\mu(\psi(B))=0$, which contradicts the assumption $\psi(B)=C$.
Thus $\psi(B_0)=C$.

> **Question 2.** Does the condition that $\pi_0(B)$ is *countable* imply that $\psi(B^0)=C$ ?

Comment: Question 2 is affirmative. Any connected Lie group has a countable base for its topology, so likewise when the component group is countable (and not otherwise, such as the pathology of discretizing a nontrivial connected Lie group). Thus, analytic homogenous spaces for such $B$ are coset spaces in such cases by results in section 1.7 of Ch. III of Bourbaki "Lie groups and Lie algebras". Then $C=B/N$ for a closed normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, so the image of $B^0$ in $C$ is an open subgroup since $B^0N$ is open in $B$. By connectedness of $C$ it then follows that $B^0\rightarrow C$ is surjective.

Comment: @nfdc23: Thank you! See [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/262189/4149).

Comment: @nfdc23: " Any connected Lie group has a countable base for its topology": Could you please give a reference to this fact?

Comment: I don't know a reference. For a Lie group $G$ and (in a coordinate chart) open ball $B\subset G$ containing 1, let $U$ be the identity component of $B\cap B^{-1}$ and let $W_n\subset G$ be the image of $U^n$ under $n$-fold multiplication $m_n:G^n\rightarrow G$. The map $m_n$ is open (e.g., the automorphism $(x,y)\mapsto (xy,y)$ of the space $G \times G$ turns $m:G \times G \rightarrow G$ into the open ${\rm{pr}}_1$), so $W_n$ is open and connected. We have $W_n\subset W_{n+1}$ since $1\in U$. Then $W=\cup_{n>0}W_n$ is a connected open subgroup, so $W=G^0$, but visibly $W$ has a countable base.

Comment: @nfdc23: Thank you! I have posted a [reference request](http://mathoverflow.net/q/262298/4149).