# Closed subgroups of a connected Lie group

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups

Is it true that for any closed subgroup $H$ of a connected Lie group $G$, the group of connected components $\pi_0(H)$ is finite or countable? (inspired by the comment of nfdc23 to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/262185/4149) ).

Comment: Yes, for exactly the same reason as in the previous answer: countability of $\pi_0(H)$ is equivalent to $H$ having a countable base for its topology, and that property is inherited under passage to closed subgroups.  So since connected Lie groups have this property, so do any of their closed subgroups.

Comment: A closed subgroup of a Lie group is a Lie subgroup, and G/H is a connected manifold, with fg hence enumerable fundamental group.