# Reference request: Any connected Lie group has a countable base for its topology

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups

I am looking for a reference for the assertion in the title. This assertion is proved in a comment of user nfdc23 to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/262185/4149). Has any proof of this assertion been published?

Comment: Try the following from the sister site: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368775/connected-lie-group-is-second-countable#1368801

Comment: A connected locally compact group is $\sigma$-compact (it coincides with the group hull of any compact neighborhood if 1), so Lindelof, and being metrizable is second-countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the easy argument given in MathSE by Cronus: if $V$ is a neighborhood of the unit homeomorphic to an open ball, $(B_n)$ a countable basis of $V$ and $D$ a dense countable subset of $V$, then the $(g_1\dots g_kB_n)$ when $k,n$ range over integers and $g_i$ over $D$, form a countable basis for $G$.

Comment: This works if the Lie group is separable. Some people put separable into the definition of a manifold, but you don't have to. So the question is whether being a Lie group implies that the underlying manifold is not too big. In particular, is there a Lie group structure on the long line?

Comment: @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Puchta. No, this always works and separable is a consequence of this sketched proof. Actually it's even simpler: $G$ is the union of all $g_1\dots g_kV$ when $k$ ranges over integers and $g_i$ over $D$; this is a countable union of separable subsets..